# Django: tweak AdminDateWidget

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Django AdminDateWidget by default displays "today" shortcut between date field and calendar icon. I want to remove this shortcut. I guess, this should be done via overriding some "render" method or smth like this, but I failed to find where this shortcut is rendered.

AdminDateWidget derives from DateInput, derived from DateTimeBaseInput, derived from Input. No sign of render process nowhere.

**Where all this stuff is rendered and how do you know that? :)**

Answer (score 0):

The widget has no `render()`-method but it [includes some Javascript.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L60)

And checking the `calendar.js`-file you'll see that it [includes the link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L247) you mentioned.

You could either override the `calendar.js`-file with an edited version or  simply add some extra Javascript to remove the link. Something like this should do the trick:

```
django.jQuery('.calendar-shortcuts').hide();
```